# Using the GNUPG Encrypt Command on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, pgp, gnupg, gpg4win

I am using the Windows port of GNU Privacy Guard 
 "light" release for version 1.0.9 installed on a windows 7 professional laptop. Installed in the default directory of : C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG .  The trustdb and keyring files are here: C:\users\\AppData\Roaming\gnupg.  Both of these folders are pathed in my environment variable PATH.

I have been following along using this tutorial: http://www.glump.net/howto/gpg_intro

and everything has worked smoothly up to   4.1 Using the GPG Encrypt Command

When i try this command to encrypt a simple text file with one line "This is a Test!", i get an error.

gpg --recipient "John Doe" --output "C:\data.txt.gpg" --encrypt "data.txt"

The error i receive is:

gpg: can't open 'data.txt': no error
gpg: data.txt: encryption failed: file open error

Any ideas why i get this error? Anything do do with Win 7 rights? I checked the text files attributes and they are fine.

Does anyone know what folder the file will be created in? And, whether or not the folder needs special rights?  As I stated above, i was able to do all the previous steps in the tutorial without an errors or issues.....including creating key pairs, and publishing a public key to file.

Thanks for any help you might be able to give me

Comment: Are you sure it's GnuPG **1.0.9**? This version doesn't seem to have ever existed; and if it did, it would've been at least 10 years old. (The latest is **2.1.0** from [Gpg4Win](http://www.gpg4win.org/).)

Comment: Hmmm, your right, there is a newer version. I was using what another expert told me to use. I took his link and downloaded it. http://files.gpg4win.org/gpg4win-light-1.0.9.exe. I will download the latest and give it a shot.

Comment: Ah, I got confused a little -- 1.0.9 is the version of the "Gpg4Win" bundle, not of GnuPG itself. Regardless, it is from 2007 and should be avoided if possible. (Gpg4win 2.1.0 bundles GnuPG 2.0.17.)

Comment: I uninstalled the old, rebooted, re-installed the new 2.1.0, and I tried it, i still get the same error.

Comment: I have also tested this on a Windows Server 2008 machine and again, i could create keys, export keys, but could not use the ecrypt command. i received the same error as i did in my test on the Win 7 machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot explain the error message; however, it might just go away after upgrading to the latest GnuPG (install using [Gpg4Win](http://www.gpg4win.org/) bundle).

The rest:

---

> Does anyone know what folder the file will be created in?

The one you specified in `--output`, of course. **`C:\data.txt.gpg`** means the file will be in **`C:\`**, or directly in the root of the `C:` drive.

If you hadn't specified a path, only the name (for example, `--output data.txt.gpg`), the file would go to the "current directory", which is shown in the console window's "prompt". For example, the following happens in the `F:\Users\Mantas` directory, and later changes to `C:\WINDOWS`:

```
F:\Users\Mantas> gpg --recipient grawity --output data.gpg --encrypt data.txt
F:\Users\Mantas> cd /d C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS> _
```

After writing this, I realized that I **may** be able to explain the error message. In your question, you haven't actually mentioned whether you are in the correct directory or not. It could just be that your `data.txt` is elsewhere... although it'd make this a *weird* error message. Still, check using `dir`.

---

> And, whether or not the folder needs special rights?

Nothing "special", but you *do* need the permission to create new files in that folder.

sually users are limited to their own "profile" folders under C:\Users, and creating files directly in C:\ may require elevation.

Comment: Ive installed the new version, and i have even tried the encrypt from the users folder  C:\Users\<mynamehere>   as well as from the C:\users\<mynamehere>\AppData\Roaming\gnupg  folder  - still the same error

Comment: I am able to manually create a file, be right clicking in the folder and creaing a new text file.  NOTE: I have also tested it by psecifying the path of the file and where the encrypted file will be written too. Tried it in a number of locations - with no success - same error.

Comment: +1 from where did you get the command line switches ? I want to execute with console , But I have many params to declare. from where do you have the list ? can you provide a link ? Thank you very much .

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The most important ones are listed by `gpg --help`. If you want all possible options and commands, see the [online docs](http://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG.html#Invoking-GPG) or – on Unixes – the manual page, `man gpg`.